# Cinder Volumes for LXD Instances in Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: openstack, lxd

I understand that volumes for nova-compute-lxd instances were in the roadmap for 16.04. Is it possible to make cinder volumes available to lxd instances in 16.04.1?

Answer (score 1):

For OpenStack Mitaka (as shipped in 16.04) its not possible to use Cinder volumes of any type with instances created using the Nova LXD driver.

For OpenStack Newton, its possible to use Cinder iSCSI volumes for persistent block storage, but there are some limitations - specifically only the ext4 filesystem type can be used within an unprivileged container and only when the kernel support is enabled

```
echo Y | sudo tee /sys/module/ext4/parameters/userns_mounts
```

You can use OpenStack Newton on Ubuntu 16.04 using the Ubuntu Cloud Archive:

```
sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:newton
```

Future OpenStack releases should have support for Ceph as well - that's currently work in progress and has not landed yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself after struggling with nova-compute-lxd installation. The answer is the 16.04.1 Mitaka relase does not support it.

Upon volume attachment I got an error in the driver.py module which refers to an unsupported feature. Master seem to have support but that seems to be far from production.

```
In driver.py one can read
   def attach_volume(self, context, connection_info, instance, mountpoint,
                      disk_bus=None, device_type=None, encryption=None):
        """Attach block device to a nova instance.
        Attaching a block device to a container requires a couple of steps.
        First os_brick connects the cinder volume to the host. Next,
        the block device is added to the containers profile. Next, the
        apparmor profile for the container is updated to allow mounting
        'ext4' block devices. Finally, the profile is saved.
        The block device must be formatted as ext4 in order to mount
        the block device inside the container.
        See `nova.virt.driver.ComputeDriver.attach_volume' for
        more information/
```

I wonder when it will be possible to use storage with LXD as currently this can be seen as a significant limitation...